# How can I convert String to Uri and apply to ImageView attribute src with DataBinding in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I'm using FirebaseFirestore and getting user data from it.
the data has a name, email, and imageUri. but the imageUri type isn't Uri. it's String.
so I have to convert the data to Uri.
so I used Uri.parse(String)
and also I'm using DataBinding and ViewModel.

here is the snippet.

```
var userImage = MutableLiveData<Uri>()  
var userName = MutableLiveData<String>() 
var userEmail = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun initializeUser() {
    firebaseDB.collection(DATA_USERS).document(userId!!).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            val user = it.toObject(User::class.java)
            user?.let {
                userImage.value = Uri.parse(user?.userImageUri)
                userName.value = user?.userName
                userEmail.value = user?.userEmail
            }
        }
}
```

and this is XML.

```
     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/info_userProfile"
          android:layout_width="80dp"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:src="@{viewModel.userImage}" />
```

the name and email is good working. but the imageView doesn't.

How can I solve it?

Comment: use bindadapters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BindingAdapter` as below:

```
 public class DataBindingAdapterUtil {
        @BindingAdapter("android:src")
        public static void setImageUri(ImageView view, Uri userImage) {
            view.setImageURI(userImage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am so happy to help you. Please mark as answer if it solves your issue